# Regex to match HTML self closing <a/> tags (using PHP)

Tags: php, regex

I had successfully used this regex to match and remove u, b, i and em self closing tags (`<b/>`, `<i/>`, ...):

```
$text = preg_replace('#<(u|b|i|em)(\s[^/>]*)?/>#', '', $text);
```

Now I also have to remove inline self closing HTML `<a/>` tags in a string, which content slash `/` characters in href attribute value (example: `<a href="https://www.example.com/en-us/cinema" target="_blank" type="[object Object]"/>`). So I can't just append `|a` in my regex list.

To avoid adding a second `preg_replace` line to match self closing `a` tags, how could I modify my existing regex?
Thanks for any hints

Comment: Why didn't you try `.*?` instead of `[^/>]*` from the start? `'#<(?:u|b|i|em)(?:\s.*?)?/>#s'`?

Comment: sglessard, please check the answers below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would do it :

```
$text = preg_replace('#<(u|b|i|em|a)(\s[^>]*)?/>#', '', $text);
```

Answer (score 0):

With `[^/>]*`, you negate  `/` or `>` as individual characters. Negate the sequence with

```
$text = preg_replace('#<(a|u|b|i|em)(\s(?:(?!/>)[^>])*)?/>#', '', $text);
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/aO27En/2).

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but I gave a try to your answer and it doesnt work. For example it matches this whole string : `<i id="U10138093770sTH">Text</i>, <i>Text</i> Text <a href=""/>`

Comment: @sglessard Thank you for feedback. I fixed the regex.